# Should directories be named in singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm trying to be **consistent** in my system with some **logic** to name a directory either *singular* or *plural*.

#### Examples of directory names

- document(s)
- language(s)
- apple(s)

The way I see it now is: everything should be named singular although it's strange in some cases.

#### Logic

The directory `languages` implies that you have more than one language.
The directory `language` is agnostic of it. You could named it `directory of language`, but for common sense you just ignores the first word.

I've seen some rules about the content of the directory:
- `plural` if homogeneous and `singular` for heterogeneous.

#### The problem

There's some rule for this?

#### Edit

This can be anything you want to label! My question is: how you do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a filing system naming convention, not "use of English" as such.

Comment: This can be a directory, this can be a folder, this can be your drawer, this can be anything you want to label.

Comment: OK... if it's a drawer, do you put "Tribbles" on the outside, or "Tribble"? [Welcome to ELU, by the way!]

Comment: `Tribble` seems weird. But `Tribble drawer` no. Perhaps they're equivalent.

Comment: In "Tribble drawer", *Tribble* is used as an adjective, and adjectives are not inflected for number. But "Tribbles drawer" would probably work. There **may** be a question here if you can get away from naming conventions: use drawer labels. (**Names** are entirely arbitrary: you could name your directory "Eleanor" and it would function just as well. That's why they are off-topic.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use plurals if there's even the possibility of there being multiple items in that directory (whether now, in the past, or in the future). If on your desk you had a box labelled "Pencils" which contained five pencils, and you took four out, you wouldn't suddenly decide that the "Pencils" label was incorrect and needed to be replaced with one that just said "Pencil". You'd just think that you were running out of pencils.

On the other hand, if there will never be more than one item in that directory, no matter what happens in the future, then it would probably be more intention-revealing to use a singular name. This doesn't happen that often, though, because if there's only ever going to be one item in a directory, you don't really need a directory (unless that "one item" is actually made up of several files).

On the whole, I would use pluralized names unless I had a very good reason to use a singular.

Comment: However, "Vacation Stuff" rather than "Vacations", unless you keep the files for multiple vacations in a single folder.

Comment: Well, both of those names are pretty terrible in that scenario, anyway. If you want to have one directory per vacation, giving those directories names like "vacation stuff" is a good way to end up having to check inside several directories trying to remember which vaguely-named directory contains the files for your 2012 trip to Egypt. Better would be "Egypt Vacation, 2012" for example - singular, because there will only ever be one such vacation (unless you invent a time machine so that you can go back and take another!).

Comment: The last paragraph made my mind more clear. Thank you. Would be nice to see more discussion but it seems that this is relative/uninteresting perhaps..

Comment: I do not agree with this answer at all. A "directory" is a "container for items". If you only have one item in there, you probably don't need a wrapping directory for this item. Therefore I prefer to always use singular. In a coding project, the "src" folder is also singluar, which is kind of the standard nowadays. Going with this approach removes this headache completely.

Comment: @codepleb "src" is an abbreviation and thus has no category of number. How would the plural of src look like? "src" can equally abbreviate "source code" as it can abbreviate "source codes" or "sources". Using an abbreviation is a rather poor counter example. The standard home folders in all three major operating systems say "Documents" and "Pictures", all plural, so I also argue that singular is standard nowadays. Unix folder abbreviations on the other hand where rather arbitrarily chosen, see https://0cn.de/z4j4